# Extending getopts from sourced script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to extend the getopts from the sourced script as below.
if an option other than a,b,c,d is passed in, it needs to print "invalid option" and exit.

script_a.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
script_a_getopts() {
   while getopts 'a:b:' OPT; do
      case "$OPT" in
         a)
           a=$OPTARG
           ;;
         b)
           b=$OPTARG
           ;;
         *)
           echo "invalid option"
           exit 1
           ;;
      esac
   done
}
```

script_b.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source script_a.sh
while getopts ':c:d:' OPT; do
case "$OPT" in
c)
   c=$OPTARG
   ;;
d)
   d=$OPTARG
   ;;
 [?])
   script_a_getopts $@
esac
done


echo "a=$a"
echo "b=$b"
echo "c=$c"
echo "d=$d"
```

When I run the script, it don't work as expected, obviously I am making a mistake.

```
$ ./script_b.sh -c cat -d dog -a apple -b boy
a=
b=
c=cat
d=dog
```

Didn't throw error when `-x` is passed.

```
$ ./script_b.sh -x
a=
b=
c=
d=
```

Comment: Och, is `script_a_getopts`  the same as `script_a.sh`? Each script is run in a subshell, you have to decide how you want to transfer environment from a subshell to the parent shell.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: You have to rollback the OPTIND before calling `script_a_getopts`.

```
case "$OPT" in
c)
   c=$OPTARG
   ;;
 ...
 [?])
   let OPTIND--
   script_a_getopts $@
esac
done
```

Long Answer:

The `getopts` track which arguments have been processed using the `OPTIND` variable. When the top `getopts` recognized unknown item, it has already 'consumed' it by moving OPTIND to the next argument. To get `script_a_getopts` to process that argument, the OPTIND need to be rolled back to point to the unprocessed argument.

The `let OPTIND--` will allow the unrecognized argument to be re-processed.

Side note, if you want to allow options to be placed in arbitrary order (`-c cat -a apple -d dog -b boy`) you will have to repeat the same in the `script_a_getopts`. This will require improved error processing in `script_a_getopts` function.